# Center align two text elements without overlap in a rectangle

Tags: d3.js, svg

So we have a two text elements in a rectangle. The first text element is a font icon similar to a circle, the second is a text. We now want to align this in the CENTER of the rectangle so that the circle comes first and then the text (like a bullet point). However how do we do this in this case

```
            percentageEntering
                .append('svg:rect')
                .style('fill', '#F3F3F4')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);

            percentageEntering
                .append('svg:text')
                .attr('x', width / 2)
                .attr('y', height / 2)
                .attr('dy', '0.35em')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('font-family', 'Material Icons')
                .style('font-size', '20px')
                .style('fill', d => this.subBreadcrumbPercentageColors[d.depth])
                .text('some_icon');

            percentageEntering
                .append('svg:text')
                .attr('x', width / 2)
                .attr('y', height / 2)
                .attr('dy', '0.35em')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .style('font-size', d => {
                    const size = ((legendData.length - 2) > 0)
                        ? 12 - (legendData.length - 2)
                        : 12;
                    return `${size}px`;
                })
                .text(d => {
                    return d.quantity + ' - ' + d.name + ((nodeArray.length === 3) ? ' %' : '');
                });
```

**EDIT**
After the changes proposed by @Gerardo, the following is the output. So firstly I had to add

[image]

```
.style('font-family', "'open sans'")
```

To make the text not use the icon fonts, also in addition to that (e.g. :- `some_icon` represents an icon). So how could I make sure these styles are not spilled over into the child? And noticed that the text is not vertically center, for which when I add a `y` parameter the icon and text overlaps then.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple fix for your case is appending the second `<text>` element as a `<tspan>`. Like this:

```
percentageEntering
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', width / 2)
    .attr('y', height / 2)
    .attr('dy', '0.35em')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('font-family', 'Material Icons')
    .style('font-size', '20px')
    .style('fill', d => this.subBreadcrumbPercentageColors[d.depth])
    .text('some_icon')
    .append('tspan')
    .style('font-size', d => {
        const size = ((legendData.length - 2) > 0) ? 12 - (legendData.length - 2) : 12;
        return `${size}px`;
    })
    .text(d => {
        return d.quantity + ' - ' + d.name + ((nodeArray.length === 3) ? ' %' : '');
    });
```

Since you applied the `text-anchor` to the parent text, everything (that is, the `<text>` element and its `<tspan>` child) should be positioned at the centre.

Here is a demo:

```js
const x = 50,
  y = 20,
  width = 150,
  height = 50;
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "wheat")
  .style("border", "gray");

const text = svg.append("text")
  .attr('x', x + width / 2)
  .attr('y', y + height / 2)
  .attr('dy', '0.35em')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('font-family', 'Material Icons')
  .style('font-size', '20px')
  .style('fill', "red")
  .text('\u25CF')
  .append('tspan')
  .style('fill', "darkslategray")
  .text(" foo bar baz");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Could you have a look at the edit I posted in the main question regarding after applying the changes you suggested, which did work but introduced some other problems that needs resolving.

Comment: @MilindaD You have to set the new font family for the tspan element, as well as removing the dy attribute.

Comment: Alright so the question now is how do I center the element vertically without adding the `dy` attribute.

Comment: @MilindaD I'm not following: you just have to *remove* the `dy` attribute from the tspan element, it will be on the same vertical position of the parent text.

Comment: I think perhaps Gerardo meant remove the `dy` from the element that is now a `<tspan>`. You won't want to remove it from the main `<text>` element, if you want to keep your vertical centering. .  It seems to have gone missing from his demo snippet, so I've put it back.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulLeBeau. I also thought about suggesting OP to use `dominant-baseline: central`, but I'm not sure about their needs (since they used `dy` in the original code).